# How does `:w !sudo tee %` work

Tags: vim, sudo, tee

If you open a file that you don't have permission to write to in vim, then decide you need to change it, you can write your changes without exiting vim by doing `:w !sudo tee %`
I don't understand how this can work. Can you please dissect this?
I understand the `:w` part, it writes the current buffer to disk, assuming there already is a file name associated with it, right?
I also understand the `!` which executes the `sudo tee` command and `%` represents the current buffer content right?
But still don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The structure `:w !cmd` means "write the current buffer *piped* through command".  So you can do, for example `:w !cat` and it will pipe the buffer through `cat`.

Now `%` is the *filename* associated with the buffer

So `:w !sudo tee %` will pipe the contents of the buffer through `sudo tee FILENAME`.  This effectively writes the contents of the buffer out to the file.

Comment: And what is `tee`?

Comment: `tee` is a Linux command used to split streams, like a "T-splitter" in plumbing. More info at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Answer (score 11):

`%` represents the current buffer's filename, not its contents.

so `:w !sudo tee %` means pipe the current buffer to `sudo tee [currentfilename]`.

`tee` is being run as root, so has write access to save its stdin to the file.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work

Answer (score 4):

Not quite right!

`!command` runs command as a [filter](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#filter) command, which get text from `stdin`, do something and output to `stdout`.

By using `w`, you pushed file content to `stdin` of `sudo tee %`. `%` is special register in vim, which holds the name of current file.

So you got `sudo tee FILENAME`, which will push `tee` `stdin` - file content - to current file.

Comment: `:!command` is a filter (cf. `:h !`), while `:w !command` is not, it just executes `command` with the current file as `stdin` (cf. `:h :w_c`).  To wit: `:w !sed /./d` doesn't change the content of the current buffer. But the recipe is indeed not quite right for another reason, `%` needs to be escaped: `:exec 'w !sudo tee ' . shellescape(expand('%', 1))`.  The original command doesn't work with, say, filenames with spaces.